# How to insert new elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm very new in Angular but I start to make a task and I'm looking for help in design.

I need that on every select update new one blue box will be added on the page.

**index.html**

```
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9" ng-controller="selectController">
          <select class="form-control"
          ng-model="selectedItem"
          ng-options="item.Title for item in items"
          ng-change="clickOnOption()">
            <option label="" value="">Nothing selected</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-12 boxes-container"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
// MODULE
var creatorApp = angular.module('creatorApp', []);

// CONTROLLERS
creatorApp.controller('selectController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
       {ID: '1', Title: 'Plan 1'},
       {ID: '2', Title: 'Plan 2'},
       {ID: '3', Title: 'Plan 3'},
       {ID: '4', Title: 'Plan 4'},
    ];

    $scope.selectedItem = '';

    $scope.clickOnOption = function(){
        console.log($scope.selectedItem.Title);
        //old noble jquery
        $('.boxes-container').append('<div class="col-md-3" style="height: 30em; background-color:#0000FF;"></div><div class="col-md-1"></div>');

    };

}]);
```

So I feel like something wrong in my code, I started use jquery again and it looks like I need to use directive or something like that. But how I can understand I should use directive in my case.

Sorry for my noob question. But I'm really confused with directives in Angular.

**update**
Sorry, but I didn't see something new for me in a related topic.
From the topic: **If you don't know, ask!**

Comment: The directive you need already exists. `ng-repeat`. You just tell it what data to repeat on and the controller adds to that data. You don't have to worry about manipulating the DOM. Your template describes what the DOM should do and the controller gives it the parameters to do it.

Comment: You are thinking jQuery..Think **Angular**

Comment: @RayonDabre not sure that is very helpful when OP is asking how to think angular. Already stated they know it's not right